# mongoose through mongo atlas TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

i am using mongoose and i encountered this problem after moving from the local mongodb server (mongod) to mongodb atlas cloud : TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

here's a snippet of the get code causing the problem

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
Item.find({}, function(err, results) {
    //Item is a mongoose model
    if (results.length === 0) {
        item.save();
        res.redirect("/");
    } else {
        res.render('toDoLists', { Title: title, addedItems: results });
        //using ejs
    }

});
```

});

here's the whole code in github :

https://github.com/oubaydos/toDoList-webDevLearningPath/blob/main/app.js

Comment: check error before any operation `console.log(err)`

Comment: @turivishal i tried it, and it's not giving much info :            Emitted 'error' event on Function instance at:
    at C:\Users\**\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4888:13
    at C:\Users\**\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:16:11
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)

Comment: Possibly a connection problem, you want to check your connection. The TypeError is telling you that `response` is undefined.

Comment: @ISAE i dont think it's a connection problem, every thing works fine if i use mongo command (client console) not mongoose. the problem started after i moved to mongodb atlas, it seems like if the interpeter couldn't create item model. it would be great if you checked the code in github, and tell me what do you think !

Comment: Well on first glance in your app.js the mongoose.connect is poining to your localhost, not to any atlas connection

Comment: @ISAE thanks man, i was looking to solve the undefined error, and totally forgot to connect to the database. the problem now is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to ISAE i found that the problem was in the connection with the mongodb atlas database, i had a connection with the localhost instead.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying cause for the error is that your declared schema isn't really a schema at all.
You need to declare it as a mongoose schema, so instead of

```
const itemsSchema = {
    name: String
};
```

You should do:

```
const itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});
```

reference: [mongoose.js docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#schemas)